Two definitions of a monad on an ∞-category
In the literature on $\infty$-categories (quasi-categories) I found two different definitions of a monad on an $\infty$-category, and I don't understand the relation between them.

The first definition appears in Jacob Lurie "Derived Algebraic Geometry II: Noncommutative Algebra". He

defines a monoidal $\infty$-category as a coCartesian fibration $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes}\to N(\Delta)^{op}$ with some properties;
defines an algebra object in a monoidal $\infty$-category as a section of this fibration $N(\Delta^{op})\to \mathcal{C}^{\otimes}$ with some properties;
constructs the monoidal $\infty$-category of endofunctors ${\rm End}^{\otimes}(\mathcal{C})\to N(\Delta)^{op}$;
and then defines a monad as an algebra object in the $\infty$-category of endofunctors.


The second definition appears in Emily Riehl, Dominic Verity, "Homotopy coherent adjunctions and the formal theory of monads". They work with categories enriched over quasi-categories. They consider a  quasi-categorically enriched category $\underline{\rm Mnd}$ with one object and the hom-set defined as (the nerve of) the augmented simplex category $\Delta_+$. Then they define a "homotopy coherent monad" as a simplicial functor $$\underline{\rm Mnd} \to \underline{\rm qCat}_\infty$$
to the quasi-categorically enriched category of quasi-categories.


Question: What is the relation between these two definitions? Are they equivalent in some sense?

This paper (and specifically Section 8 thereof) by Rune Haugseng essentially fully answers the question, proving that the two notions are indeed equivalent.
